# Python - parse all videos from site

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, request

I need some help with a parser on site ex: https://filmy.plus/kategoria/Horror

I wrote some code and all working fine, but only for 12 videos (First load)

```
url = 'https://filmy.plus/kategoria/Horror'
response = get(url)
#print(response.text[:6000])
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
type(html_soup)
movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'movie-box-3 movie-box-search')
print(url, "\nLiczba Filmów: ", len(movie_containers),"\n")

for i in range(0,len(movie_containers)):
    first_movie = movie_containers[i]
    print(first_movie.a.h2.text)
    print('https://filmy.plus'+first_movie.a['href']+'\n')
```

[image]
But how to load all videos? I need to click "Pokaż więcej" 3-4 times? for load all video from the site. I dont know how to bypass it and get all links from url

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@DivideBy0` [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54645208/2255764) you can scrape all data with [API](https://filmy.plus/jquery_kategorie_pokaz_wiecej.php?kategoria=Horror&strona=1):

```
import re
import requests

result = {}
for i in range(100):
    response = requests.get('https://filmy.plus/jquery_kategorie_pokaz_wiecej.php?kategoria=Horror&strona={}'.format(i+1))
    for film in response.json()['wynik']:
        title = re.findall('title=\"(.*)\"', film)[0]
        link = 'https://filmy.plus' + re.findall('href=\"(.*)\" ', film)[0]
        result[title] = link

print('Videos found: {}'.format(len(result)))
for i, el in enumerate(result.items()):
    print('{}. {} {}'.format(i+1, el[0], el[1]))
```

You'll get on output:

```
Videos found: 66
1. Anakondy: Polowanie na Krwawą Orchideę https://filmy.plus/film2/Anakondy.Polowanie.Na.Krwawa.Orchidee
2. Uciec przeznaczeniu https://filmy.plus/film/Uciec+przeznaczeniu-2009-378067
3. Jad https://filmy.plus/film/Jad-1981-11436
4. Venom https://filmy.plus/film/Venom-1971-37749
5. Zakonnica https://filmy.plus/film/Zakonnica-2018-777024
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks man! I have one more question! How to add for this output ordinal number? example:  `1. Title of vide Link to video` the next is `2. Title of vide Link to video` etc?

Comment: Thanks man!!!! Last question! How to add on first or last line "Videos found: [Numer of last ordinal number]"   (I add solved + point for You :))

Comment: no problem You very help me with that code, that working perfect but i have (i think? :D) Last question :p Is it possible to remove the repetition? Or display the movie only once? Ex: Monster https://filmy.plus/serial/Monster-2004-192515 is 2x, Jad https://filmy.plus/film/Jad-2005-220195 is 2x etc :)

Answer (score 1):

Hard Way

selenium webdriver simulated click next page

Easy Way

Use the website api

https://filmy.plus/jquery_kategorie_pokaz_wiecej.php?kategoria=Horror&strona=1

Comment: How i can parse that code? Delete ex "\n\t\t\t\t\t\t \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t" for normal html / lxml code?